# Get data from already running service in onCreate of an activity

Tags: java, android, android-service

Let's say a service 'MyService' is already running, doing some work like copying a file in background, before an activity, 'MyActivity' is launched. Then user launches the activity. How can I retrieve what file is being copied in MyService when MyActivity starts so that I can show it in UI?

I haven't attached a code because I want a generic answer to this. The task could be anything, like downloading a file. I'm learning coding and experimenting with services. So, I'm just copying a bunch of big files in a service.

If needed, I'll post the code.

Comment: A generic answer to this is [Bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services)

Comment: I followed exact same guide before posting the question here. In onCreate I wrote this, if (mBound) { String s = CopyService.getFileName() }. For some reason, onServiceConnected gets called after this code gets executed, so mBound is always false.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this is to have the service expose a RxJava bus (or similar) where it pushes updates on what it is doing. Then the Activity will subscribe to this bus in onResume and unsubscribe in onPause and will display info based on what is being pushed on the bus.

You could have a single bus, where the event itself carries data (like the percentage of copy), or you could have multiple buses, for instance one for state (idle, copying, ...) and another one for details on the state (like a bus for percentage of copy done).

A possible implementation for the states would be

```
sealed class State {
    object Idle : State()
    class Copying(val percent: Float): State()
}
```

then in your Service you would have

```
val stateBus = BehaviorSubject.create<State>()
```

then

```
stateBus.onNext(Copying(.5f))
```

Comment: Why `Rx` and `Kotlin`? Is this what the OP asked for?

Comment: The OP asked for a generic answer. What is wrong with RxJava and Kotlin? It's a valid solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned I need the code in Java (as I don't know Kotlin) and possibly without the use of external libraries. The advantage of doing things natively, and manually for me, would be getting better acquainted with code and understanding how it all works. As I'm very new to coding in general. But your code will be helpful for someone wanting  Rx and Kotlin. So no probs.